# Client Side JavaScript Code Analyser

Tags: javascript, jquery, text-analysis

Is there a JavaScript Code analyser which can be used on the client side to analyze code patterns? 
I've found the following but it seems that this is just for regular text and gives you the `=` sign etc. I need some code analysis which can run on the client side (JS code), is there any which can be used?

```js
function parseData() {
  var rawData = document.getElementById('data').value.trim(),  
      result,
      output = $('#output'),
      table = $('table').remove(),
      header,
      row,
      cell,
      ul,
      slice,
      wpm = [],        
      wpmAvg = [];

  output.empty();
  table.find('thead, tbody').empty();

  if ($('[name="format"]:checked').val() === 'text') {
    // Simple text        
    result = analyzeText(rawData);
    output.append('Word count: ' + result.count + '<br><br>Frequent words:<br>');
    ul = $('<ul>');
    _.forEach(result.frequentWords, function(value, key) {
      ul.append('<li>' + value.word + ': ' + value.count + '</li>');
    });
    output.append(ul);       
  }
  else {
    // JSON
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(rawData);
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log('Error parsing JSON', e);
    }
    header = table.find('thead');
    body = table.find('tbody');
    row = $('<tr>');
    body.append(row);
    // Loop over slices
    _.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
      slice = '';
      // Loop over statements
      _.forEach(value, function(value, key) {
        slice += value.words + ' ';
      });

      result = analyzeText(slice);

      addCell(slice, key);

    });
    $.plot('#wpm', [wpm], {
      xaxes: [{
        axisLabel: 'Time index (1-minute increments)',
      }],
      yaxes: [{
        position: 'left',
        axisLabel: 'Words per minute',
      }]
    });
    output.append(table);
  }

  function addCell(data, index) {
    var cell1, cell2, ul1, ul2, result;
    cell1 = $('<td>');
    cell2 = $('<td>');
    ul1 = $('<ul>');
    ul2 = $('<ul>');
    cell1.append(ul1);
    cell2.append(ul2);
    row.append(cell1, cell2);
    result = analyzeText(data);
    header.append('<th>' + index + '</th><th class="subText">(' + result.count + ')</th>');
    wpm.push([index, result.count]);
    _.forEach(result.frequentWords, function(value, key) {
      ul1.append('<li>' + value.word + '</li>');
      ul2.append('<li>' + value.count + '</li>');
    });
  }
}

function analyzeText(rawData) {
  var result = {
    count: 0,
    frequentWords: []
  },
      data = rawData.split(/[\s.,]+/g)
  counts = {},
    countsArray = [],
    commonWords = [ 
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,            
    '-',
    'a',
    'about',
    'function',
    'object'
  ];

  if (!data[data.length]) {
    data.splice(-1, 1);
  }

  // Word count
  result.count = data.length;

  // Word frequency (filtered for common words, sorted descending by count)
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (!counts.hasOwnProperty(data[i].toLowerCase())) {
      counts[data[i].toLowerCase()] = 1;
    }
    else {
      counts[data[i].toLowerCase()] += 1;
    }
  }    
  _.forEach(counts, function(value, key) {
    if (commonWords.indexOf(key.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
      countsArray.push({
        word: key.toLowerCase(),
        count: value
      });
    }
  });
  countsArray = _.sortBy(countsArray, 'count').reverse();    
  _.forEach(countsArray, function(value, index) {
    if (value.count > 1) {
      result.frequentWords.push(value);            
    }
  });

  return result;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
}
table, tr, td, th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
th, td {
  padding: 4px 8px;    
}
.subText {
  color:#999;
  font-style: italic;
}
#wpm {
  width:600px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.js"></script>

<textarea id="data" cols="80" rows="20" placeholder="Paste text or JSON here"></textarea><br />
<label for="text"><input type="radio" name="format" checked value="text" id="text"> Simple text</label>
<button type="button" onclick="parseData()">Analyze text</button>
<br><br>
<div id="output"></div><br><br>
<div id="wpm"></div>
<table>
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fxn5q8y0/6/

Comment: Are you talking about regular expressions?

Comment: @Jai - maybe under the hood I want to provide some code which will be analyzed regard some keyword structure or maybe some pattern etc

Comment: Please be more specific.. What are you need **exactly** `text analysis` is not enough.

Comment: @MoshFeu - I need some kind of mechanism  which take a js file and provide how many function is there ,how many vars how many object ,I want to provide the file as string and provide some keyword to find in the file...there is open source which I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Simply loop through each element in a scope and detect its type.

Here a quick example:

```js
var analyse = function(obj){
  var results = {}
  
  for(var b in obj) { // for each element
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(b)){
      var detectedType = ( typeof obj[b] ) // detect the type
      if (!(detectedType in results)){ results[detectedType] = 0; } // if the type was detected for the first time, add its name to the results
      
      results[detectedType]++; // increase the counter for the detected type
    }
  }
  
  return results;
}



/**
  example for a testObject
**/

testObject = {
  a: undefined, // type undefined
  b: { xx: "xx", yy: 123 }, // type object
  c: false, // type boolean
  d: 987, // type number
  e: "abc", // type string
  f: Symbol("foo"), // type symbol 
  g: function(){}, // type function
  h: "jkl", // type number
  i: 654 // type number
};

console.log( analyse(testObject) );
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!